# Illegal invocation при вызове SetTimeout

Tags: javascript

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div);

setTimeout(document.body.removeChild, 1000, div); //Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
setTimeout( function(){ document.body.removeChild(div);}, 1000 );
```

Правильны ли следующие рассуждения:

В первом случае на момент вызова функции removeChild сборщик мусора уже удалил переменную div (дошли до конца скрипта).
Во втором случае при объявлении безымянной функции мы взяли переменную div с помощью замыкания, увеличив количество ссылок на нее, поэтому и смогли ей воспользоваться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, рассуждения неправильны.

"сборщик мусора уже удалил переменную div" - А как же ссылка, переданная в `setTimeout`? Не говоря уже о том, что сам элемент находится в DOM-дереве и никуда не девается.

В Вашем коде функция `removeChild` вызывается в чужом контексте - `window`.

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("class", "mydiv");
document.body.appendChild(div);

setTimeout(document.body.removeChild.bind(document.body), 1000, div);
```

```css
.mydiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

*Update*

Передавая куда-либо метод объекта, Вы отрываете его от контекста. Вашу ошибку можно воспроизвести более простым кодом:

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("class", "mydiv");
document.body.appendChild(div);

let remove = document.body.removeChild;
remove(div);
```

Здесь (как и у Вас) метод `removeChild` вызывается в контексте `window`, у которого, конечно, нет child-а `div`.

Comment: Не могли бы пояснить, почему произошла потеря контекста? Я сталкивался с такой проблемой, когда где-то в коде вызываемой функции использовалось this,  именно поэтому необходимо сделать обертку, например bind. Однако здесь же явно указано document.body, т.е. явная ссылка на объект, без this. Откуда тогда проблема?

Comment: Кажется понял. document.body.removeChild - ссылка на метод. При вызове внутри себя он использует this. Если вызывать метод через точку (document.body.removeChild), то контекстом служит document.body. Если же напрямую, то контекст this устанавливается в window. Так правильно?

Comment: @yataw Да, правильно.